# Formula not having updated value in After Trigger : Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, formula-field, after-trigger

```
updateTemplate((List<Object>)tp.newList, (Map<Id, Object>)tp.newMap, (Map<Id, Object>)tp.oldMap);
```

In the method I am querying updateTemplate I have a query as below

```
Map<Id, Object> requests= new Map<Id, Object>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, formulaField__c from Object__r) Object WHERE Id IN: requestMap.keySet()]);
```

`requestMap` is the `(Map<Id, Object>)tp.newMap`. Now the problem is that, here while querying `formulaField__c` is old value, and is not showing `newvalue`. I have written `System.debug` statements and can confirm this. 
The whole logic is written in isafter trigger. Do I need to put delay for few miliseconds so that the formula values gets updated in the DB?

Answer (score 3):

Formula fields are calculated when queried from the database. There's no need to "wait a few milliseconds." However, specific types of formulas that depend on specific types of data might not be correct. For example, if the formula uses a rollup summary field, the formula will still show the old values, because the rollup summary field is not calculated until after triggers run.

Comment: It's not a rollup summary field, but just depends on few different field values and lookup, which is being populated by external system. But in my afterupdate trigger, those query still gives old values. Do I need to include the lookups also in the query?

Comment: @RahulJain If data is coming from an external system, it won't be available in your trigger no matter what you do.

Comment: external system means external system is updating the Object.  And the trigger gets fired after they update it.

Comment: @RahulJain Without seeing all of the code involved, etc, I can't answer your question definitively. I'm saying, in the general sense, that when you query a formula, it **is** derived off of the available data in the database. It's up to you to determine **if** the data is actually available or not. If it's not available, you can't query it, if it is, you can.